# How should I handle search when data keeps updating via websockets?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, search, websocket, real-time

- I have a real time news feed that keeps updating via websockets in Vue.js using Vuex store and express server
- Lets say you went to the search bar and typed new york
- I will fetch all 'new york' related articles from the database
- But since I am also connected to websockets, when the news sources that I scan change, I push new data items to each connected client
- How do I handle this?

**Questions**

- Should I block the updates?
- Should I only show 'new york' related new items?

**Options**

- Let it be as it is. A person types 'new york' in the search box and is looking currently at the screen, new item appears, push it to the user regardless
- Filter the item on the client side for the search filter 'new york' if the phrase is present in the new item, show it else dont
- Filter the item on the server side, not sure how this happens using WS

Comment: You could have information on current search string (and generaly filters) for each connected socket stored on server. Then, before pushing event to client, you could check if new item matches current search string and filters. I would advise against filtering these on client, as changes in logic will result in having to change those in multiple places

Comment: @IvanJakab but the search term will keep changing each time the person hits enter or clicks the search button and filter ll keep changing each time a different dropdown item is selected, should you do a post request for these each time or use websocket to send a message to the server each time any of these change

Comment: That was my idea, use websockets each time filters change (although make sure to use debouncing). However, I would like to point out that this is only viable if server can handle it - if you can store all this data on server (consider storing it in redis). If server can't handle it, client-side filtering might be a better option, but in most cases I am against extensive client side logic.